# is it possible to add annotation but do not change map view region in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview

I want to use *regionDidChangeAnimated* delegate get current region then request data from server and add new annotation, but when add new annotation the mapView's region will changed also, so this will loop forever?Anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

MapView addAnnotation does not change a maps region.  [MapView setRegion] does, as does a user via the UI.

If you're doing these server round-trips, you should only add the annotation if its going to be visible (based on the currently visible region), and don't do setRegion.

Answer (score 0):

The map region changes if the callout for that annotation will change. Otherwise, you're moving it yourself from code to fit all the annotations in view, maybe ?

In either case,  use a BOOL variable to indicate that the map will move because of the code, and in the delegate method check if the map was moved by the user or by your code.